# Symfony2: FormFactory which arguments?

Tags: forms, service, symfony, factory

I want to use Symfony's FormFactory for handling FormType and FormHandler.

Unfortunatly I don't know what arguments are required to start the FormFactory service, I looked into the constructor of the Form-Class but there where allot of dependencies I can't really order.

```
    <service id="loc_article.form" factory-method="createNamed" factory-service="form.factory" class="Symfony\Component\Form\Form">
        <argument></argument>
        <argument></argument>
        <argument />
    </service>

    <service id="loc_article.form.type" class="LOC\ArticleBundle\Form\Type\ArticleFormType">
        <argument>LOC\ArticleBundle\Entity\Article</argument>
    </service>

    <service id="loc_article.form.handler" class="LOC\ArticleBundle\Form\Handler\ArticleFormHandler"  scope="request" >
        <argument type="service" id="loc_article.form" />
        <argument type="service" id="request" />
        <argument type="service" id="loc_article.manager" />
    </service>
```

So what arguments do I have to pass?

Comment: Are your trying to use the S2 form components by themselves outside of the S2 framework?

Comment: In my Bundle moreorless.

I found this service-solution in https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle/blob/master/Resources/config/profile.xml

Do you think it is enough to define FormType and FormHandler as service??

Regards

Comment: I define FormTypes as services.  They work just fine.  Never needed to mess with FormHandlers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[CreateNamed](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/src/Symfony/Component/Form/FormFactory.php#L157) method of `FormFactory` class takes `FormType` and name of the `FormType` respectively.

**Edit:**

Actually name is not related to `FormType`. It can be any arbitrary name.

Added service declaration.

```
<service id="loc_article.form" factory-method="createNamed" factory-service="form.factory" class="Symfony\Component\Form\Form">
    <argument>los_article_form</argument>
    <argument>los_article_form_name</argument>
    <argument />
</service>


<service id="loc_article.form.type" class="LOC\ArticleBundle\Form\Type\ArticleFormType">
    <tag name="form.type" alias="los_article_form" />
    <argument>LOC\ArticleBundle\Entity\Article</argument>
</service>
```

Comment: Hi,

I added these arguments, now I am getting an UncaughtException by the FormFactory

            <service id="loc_article.form" factory-method="createNamed" factory-service="form.factory" class="Symfony\Component\Form\Form">
            <argument>loc_article.form.type</argument>
            <argument>loc_article_form</argument>
            <argument />
        </service>

Answer (score 4):

**For all [yaml](/questions/tagged/yaml) users** - A working example for [symfony](/questions/tagged/symfony) `2.4~`:

```
services:
  chocolate_factory.contact.form:
    class: Symfony\Component\Form\Form
    factory_method: createNamed
    factory_service: form.factory
    arguments: [form_name, form_name]

  chocolate_factory.contact.form.type:
    class: %anchorbrands_common.contact.form.type.class%
    arguments: [null]
    tags:
        - { name: form.type, alias: form_name}
```